# Una consulta me muestra un resultado vacío, cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Tags: mysql-workbench, subconsultas

Esta es la consulta que quiero realizar:
-- Obtener el nombre, el número de telefono, las observaciones y la duración de la visita de los visitantes Lorea y Ramón.

```
SELECT vi.Nombre, vi.NO_Móvil, ci.Duración, re.Observaciones
FROM Visitante vi
JOIN Citaprevia ci ON vi.DNI=ci.fk_DNI
JOIN Registrovisita re ON re.fk_Cod_Visita=ci.Cod_Visita
WHERE ci.Cod_Visita='1' AND ci.Cod_Visita='2';
```

No me da error, solo que me devuelve una respuesta vacía. Cuando a la condición WHERE le quito el AND y la segunda, condición me da la primera respuesta (lo que tiene relación con Lorea).

Muchas gracias

Comment: Probaste reemplazar el AND por un OR ?

Comment: Muchas gracias con OR si me funciona, me podrías explicar la diferencia entre AND y OR, porque pensé que OR no me servía para esta consulta.

Comment: Si, ahi te lo explico en una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los operadores AND y OR se utilizan para filtrar resultados con 2 condiciones.

El operador AND mostrará los resultados cuando se cumplan las 2 condiciones.

Condición1 AND condición2

El operador OR mostrará los resultados cuando se cumpla alguna de las 2 condiciones.

Condicion1 OR condicion2

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, ahora si lo entendí <3

Comment: De nada, te recuerdo marcar la respuesta que te di como la que te funciono. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías graficarlo mejor usando el español como ejemplo de las consultas. `AND` es cuando quieres que se cumpla `una condición Y otra condición`, es decir AMBAS estrictamente. Caso diferente es `OR` cuando quieres que se cumpla `una condición o/u otra condición`, si una o la otra se cumple, pasa el operador.

Comment: Yo siempre lo explico usando las mates: el `AND` es una multiplicacion: culquier cosas multiplicada por 0 (no se cumple una condicion) da 0 y el `OR` es una suma.